What do the large Christian organisations teach about the origins of the Samaritans?
The biblical description of the origin of the Samaritans is that they were moved into Samaria as part of the forced population transfer by the Assyrians after their conquest of the Kingdom of Israel.
The Samaritans themselves hold that they descend from the tribes of Ephraim and Manasseh in ancient Samaria, and split theologically at the time of the biblical priest Eli and who remained after the Assyrian deportations.
Modern genetic studies support the Samaritan narrative that they descend from indigenous Israelites:

Principal component analysis suggests a common ancestry of Samaritan and Jewish patrilineages. Most of the former may be traced back to a common ancestor in the paternally-inherited Jewish high priesthood (Cohanim) at the time of the Assyrian conquest of the kingdom of Israel.

What do the large Christian organisations such as the Catholic Church teach about the origins of the Samaritans?

I'm curious to see if the catholics or protestants who might answer will show an answer that is different than the passage from 2 Kings 17.

The OP, it seems, has misrepresented the OT teaching about the Samaritans.  Not all the Israelites were removed from the land, so Samaritans thereafter were, and are, a mixed race of Israelite and Gentiles (taken from regions within the Assyrian Empire).  The Samaritan religion also became a mixed impure syncretism of the worship of the G-d of the OT together with the worship of idols.

Well, I'm not catholic... Eastern Orthodox, but we are really big so I'll give you our answer.

Long Answer:
In the final stage of the fulfilling of Isaiah’s prophecy

“Within sixty-five years Ephraim will be broken, so that it will not be a people” (Isaiah 7:8)

Esarhaddon, king of Assyria, in the year 670 B.C., removed the Israelites living in what was the Northern Kingdom. In their place he transplanted peoples from several other nations that they had previously conquered as described in

“Then the king of Assyria brought people from Babylon, Cuthah, Ava, Hamath, and from Sepharvaim, and placed them in the cities of Samaria instead of the children of Israel; and they took possession of Samaria and dwelt in its cities. And it was so, at the beginning of their dwelling there, that they did not fear the Lord; therefore the Lord sent lions among them, which killed some of them. So they spoke to the king of Assyria, saying, ‘The nations whom you have removed and placed in the cities of Samaria do not know the rituals of the God of the land; therefore He has sent lions among them, and indeed, they are killing them because they do not know the rituals of the God of the land.’
Then the king of Assyria commanded, saying, ‘Send there one of the priests whom you brought from there; let him go and dwell there, and let him teach them the rituals of the God of the land.’ Then one of the priests whom they had carried away from Samaria came and dwelt in Bethel, and taught them how they should fear the Lord. However every nation continued to make gods of its own, and put them in the shrines on the high places which the Samaritans had made, every nation in the cities where they dwelt. The men of Babylon made Succoth Benoth, the men of Cuth made Nergal, the men of Hamath made Ashima, and the Avites made Nibhaz and Tartak; and the Sepharvites burned their children in fire to Adrammelech and Anammelech, the gods of Sepharvaim.
So they feared the Lord, and from every class they appointed for themselves priests of the high places, who sacrificed for them in the shrines of the high places. They feared the Lord, yet served their own gods—according to the rituals of the nations from among whom they were carried away. To this day they continue practicing the former rituals; they do not fear the Lord, nor do they follow their statutes or their ordinances, or the law and commandment which the Lord had commanded the children of Jacob, whom He named Israel, with whom the Lord had made a covenant and charged them, saying: ‘You shall not fear other gods, nor bow down to them nor serve them nor sacrifice to them; but the Lord, who brought you up from the land of Egypt with great power and an outstretched arm, Him you shall fear, Him you shall worship, and to Him you shall offer sacrifice. And the statutes, the ordinances, the law, and the commandment which He wrote for you, you shall be careful to observe forever; you shall not fear other gods.
And the covenant that I have made with you, you shall not forget, nor shall you fear other gods. But the Lord your God you shall fear; and He will deliver you from the hand of all your enemies.’ However they did not obey, but they followed their former rituals. So these nations feared the Lord, yet served their carved images; also their children and their children’s children have continued doing as their fathers did, even to this day” (2 Kings 17:24-41).

So the Samaritans are not a Jewish people (But we knew that already), they are rather a mix of several different peoples that worshipped multiple gods.
Over time, their worship had taken on a Jewish character but with their own peculiarities. Their primary religious text became the Torah (the Pentateuch) only, but with some variation, and excluded the other Holy Scriptures. They ended up building their own temple on Mt. Gerizim which they considered their own holy mountain instead of where Jerusalem was at the time of Alexander the Great in 322 B.C.

Short answer:
All Orthodox churches I am aware of teach (if asked) that the origins of the Samaritans are exactly as described in the Bible.
That is to say, the original peoples were forced there from Babylon, Cuthah, Ava, Hamath, and from Sepharvaim. They intermarried and eventually became the Samaritan people.

Source: Coptic Orthodox Diocese of the Southern United States.
https://suscopts.org/resources/interesting-facts/1/who-are-the-samaritans/
Source: St. Mary Orthodox Church (Cambridge, MA) (But it focuses on the Good Samaritan and only says that Samaritans are a Motley crew of intermarriages during the assyrian conquest)
https://www.stmaryorthodoxchurch.org/orthodoxy/sermons/2007/good-samaritan

New information... (Oct. 11th)
Strangely there is no early church father information that I can find on 2 Kings 17:22-41. It's almost as if the origin of the samaritans was not important theologically at all.
So my answer remains the same, the Orthodox church (arguably the 2nd largest church) teaches (if asked!) the literal same as the Bible verses regarding their origins.

This answer does not attempt to answer the question What do the large Christian organisations such as the Catholic Church teach about the origins of the Samaritans. Sources from such an organization would be an answer

@AviAvraham All Orthodox churches tend to all just point to the verse above, there is no significant other information regarding the subject that I'm aware of.

@AviAvraham To be fair large Christian organisations "such as" the Catholic Church is not the same as "What does the catholic church teach about" The orthodox church is the 2nd largest church in the world with double the amount of members of any individual protestant denomination. I am referencing sources from the 2nd largest church organization in the world. If you only want catholic please rewrite your question to explicitly ask for catholic. Thanks :)

As the OP I can say I appreciate this answer.

@User65535 Thanks :)
